# Docker Exposing ports for Flask API

Tags: linux, api, flask, docker, ports

## **Problem Statement**

I am running a Flask-based API within a Docker container that is exposed on the port 5000, however no requests are even getting to the API.

## **To reproduce**

1. Get jupyter/all-spark-notebook docker image
2. Within the Docker container, get any Flask-based API, for reproducibility purposes try https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/oreilly-flask-apis-video (for understanding a very simple Python-based API switch to v0.1 in releases)
3. Run the Docker using the standard command as described here (https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook). Forget about the notebook part, and only use `-p 5000:5000` to get the API preferred port to run. Don't use HTTPS, but do install ssh on the container. (So unless you are using a custom Dockerfile like me, you will need to enable SUDO)
4. Try to make any request to API (e.g. `http GET http://localhost:5000/customers/1`) --> *this fails* and gets different error messages depending

   - whether it is `Python based urlib request (IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None))`
   - or HTTPie based (`http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /filterReplies/aaaaa/aaaa (Caused by <class 'http.client.RemoteDisconnected'>: Remote end closed connection without response)`)
5. Check logs, where no record of any API request

## Notes

- I am running on a linux machine so no VM necessary.
- There is a difference in making a `wget http://localhost:5000` (gets `Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
  Retrying.`) and `wget http://localhost:1234` (gets `Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
  Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8888... failed: Connection refused.`) so the port is open on some level, but there just does not seem to be anything waiting on the other side?
- The original purpose of the image still works--i.e. if I specify *both* ports to be forwarded, I can still have a browser-based access to the Jupyter notebooks within the docker container. So *some* port forwarding on this machine works.

Comment: Can you bind your app in 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost? I'm not sure though.

Comment: Just to be very specific: I ran the same command except now with `-p 0.0.0.0:5000:5000` instead of normal `-p 5000:5000` appending the IP before the second number producer an error `sr/data custom-docker python3 /home/jovyan/work/flask_api/run.py
docker: Invalid ip address: 5000.` __But just as I am writing this, I understand that is not what you meant.__ Will modify the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding to `0.0.0.0` will bind your app in any interface available, localhost does not. There is one post that describes the difference between `localhost` and `0.0.0.0`, if I find I will update this post.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a code example here and so i thought I'd add in what I did in order to "bind" to `0.0.0.0` to resolve the `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.` issue.

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` being the important bit.

This should resolve the `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.` issue.

Answer (score 1):

All credit goes to [ipinak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873758/ipinak) who suggested binding the app to `0.0.0.0`, which indeed solved the problem.

Interestingly though, the app still responds on localhost. But I will take that for now.